# List event receiver to record date, when the workflow status on the item has been updated??

Tags: events, sharepoint-2010, event-handling, workflow-activity, sharepoint-list

Here is the code I have to record the date when the workflow status on an item has been updated/changed. I created  accustom column named Completed Date as a Date type in the list to display the date.

The workflow deploys fine but does not render any data under the Completed Date Column. Am I missing something?

```
namespace WorkflowDateRecorder.EventReceiver1
{
/// <summary>
/// List Item Events
/// </summary>
public class EventReceiver1 : SPItemEventReceiver
{
   /// <summary>
   /// An item is being updated.
   /// </summary>
   public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       base.ItemUpdating(properties);
       if (properties.BeforeProperties["Wokflowstatus"] != properties.AfterProperties["Wokflowstatus"])
       {
           properties.ListItem["Completed Date"] = DateTime.Now;
           properties.ListItem.Update();
           properties.Web.Update();
       }
   }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ItemUpdating` method, you should be setting your new field value using

```
properties.AfterProperties[Completed_x0020_Date] = newFieldValue;
//AfterProperties and BeforeProperties are using internal names of columns.
```

Also question is then, if your if statement is ever visited? Cause calling `ListItem.Update()` most probably would result in recursive call on this event receiver.